# Native Base Linking Issue

Tags: reactjs, native

I have been trying to use NativeBase.io provided library for React Native. However the command native-react link does not work regardless of what we do. It shows the error as mentioned below.

Now i found from somewhere that the upgrade needs to happen and than running again should solve this but after even doing that its did not.

Appreciate all of your assistance.

Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null

Answer (score 0):

I got this filled by following the following command

```
sudo sudo npm install
```

Once this is done, i just go on and run my command to open the emulator. Hope this helps to the people having the same issue.